# How do you make default option with V-bind when using an object?

Tags: vue.js, html-select, v-for

So I have the following code in vue.js:

```
<template>
...
<div v-for="guest in guests" :key="guest">
  <label for="attendance">Will  {{guest}}  be attending? </label>
    <select v-model="attendance[guest]" id='attendance'>
      <option value="yes">Yes</option>
      <option value="no">No</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
</div>
...
<script>
...
data() {
    return {
      guests: {},
      numGuests: 0,
      sleepOver: null,
      attendance: { },
    };
```

I am trying to make yes default. I've read other solutions that says the v-model overrides it. The solutions I have found seem not to apply to my specific code. I tried putting it in my attendance and it does not work. Any suggestions related to my code?

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will help you fix the issue

Step 1: First correct your model. When you are going with `v-for` always model it should be an array. so `guests` should be an `array` which having the property on `name` and `willBeAttending` property

```
data () {
return {
  guests: [{
    name: 'Jeba',
    willBeAttending: 'yes'
  },
  {
    name: 'Suthan',
    willBeAttending: 'no'
  }],
  numGuests: 0,
  sleepOver: null,
 }
}
```

Step 2: Template should be like below

```
<div v-for="(guest, $index)" in guests" :key="$index">
    <label for="attendance">Will  {{guest.name}}  be attending? </label>
      <select v-model="guest.willBeAttending" id='attendance'>
        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="no">No</option>
      </select>
      <br><br>
 </div>
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-pascal-mwr6q)

Comment: That almost did the trick! I am sending the values for guest and attendance from another page so I did this: `created() {
    this.guests = [{
      name: this.$route.query.guests,
      willBeAttending: this.coming = this.$route.query.coming,
    }];` and changed the rest of my code according to what you said. When it first loads the page I am getting: Will [ "Name" ] be attending? and no default. However if I refresh the page it gets rid of the [''] and default works.

Comment: @Sheepgirl17 I updated the demo link. try the created function like below `created() {
    this.guests = [
      {
        name: "Jeba", // this.$route.query.guests, // bind from router
        willBeAttending:
          this.$route && this.$route.query.coming
            ? this.$route.query.coming
            : "yes", // bind from router otherwise default 'yes' selection
      },
    ];
  },`

Comment: It still doesn't work. I also checked with more then one guest coming and it lists them in one line.

Comment: @Sheepgirl17 can you add your modal `guests` that would be helpful to resolve the issue.

Comment: what do you mean?